# Webpack Loader: How do I tell which file is currently being loaded in a loader?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

When I am building a loader for webpack, how do I tell which file is currently being loaded in the loader function? It would make debugging thing easier if I could only break on certain files. Reading through the documentation I can't see how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are in your loader function, you can reference `this.resource`, which will be the path to the file currently be evaluated by the loader.

```
module.exports = function(source) {
    console.log(this.resource); // path/to/current/file/being/loaded.js
}
```

You can also reference `this.resourcePath`. They both point to the same thing, from what I can tell. Not sure what the difference is.

Comment: I ran into the need for this and the answer for this when debugging through the Angular CLI's main loader.